# Cannot load primefaces default theme when I have additional folder in the URL

Tags: maven, jsf-2, primefaces, themes

Here is the POM file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
```

Web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>aristo</param-value>
```

On the main page http://localhost/helloworld/search.faces primefacs theme loads fine

Generated Page with primefaces style sheet is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/helloworld/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.faces?ln=primefaces-aristo" /><link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/helloworld/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.faces?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/helloworld/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.faces?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0"><!--

//--></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/helloworld/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.faces?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0"><!--

//--></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/helloworld/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.faces?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0"><!--

//--></script>
```

but when I access subsequent pages which is one folder down
http://localhost/helloworld/app/welcome.faces, theme is not applied. Url generated for the theme file is adding the extra folder which is in the url and thus not able to find the theme file resulting in theme not getting loaded. What should I do for the extra folder to not get added to the for the primefaces theme url...

generated page is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/helloworld/app/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-aristo" /><link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/helloworld/app/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/helloworld/app/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0"><!--

    //--></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/helloworld/app/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0"><!--

//--></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/helloworld/app/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0"><!--

//--></script>
```

code

There is no theme related code in xhtml... mentioned in web.xml and all- themes in POM file.

welcome.xhtml and search.xhtml are the same and here is the snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/WEB-INF/layouts/standard.xhtml">

<ui:define name="title">
</ui:define>
```

standard.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view contentType="text/html">....
```

**Summary of the problem**
If the url is **/helloworld/search.faces**  generated in the page is `/helloworld/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.faces?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.0"` ... and theme loads fine.

When the url is ( is one folder deep) theme does not load **/helloworld/app/welcome.faces** path generated is in the page is `href="/helloworld/app/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-aristo ...` see the **app** directory that is added.... This is causing 404 erros for this resouce as it is not able to find it.

Is there a way to control the generated primefaces theme path ?

Comment: Show the pages, templates etc… but make them as minimal as possible but fully valid

Comment: for the second url the page shows fine but without the theme appied. When I inspect, seeing 404 errors for the below url

Comment: Sorry, I meant the xhtml source.  Because I have lots and lots of subpages but none fail…  and btw, you groupId of the themes is wrong I think.  It should be 'org.primefaces.themes'

Comment: There is no theme related code in xhtml... mentioned in web.xml and all- themes in POM file.

Comment: You have no 8080 in you url.  Do you have a reverse proxy in front of your appserver?  If so, does it work if you access directly?

Comment: I did use the appropriate port number in my case its 9081 ( websphere appvserver)but did not uncle in this post to keep it simple... In both cases I am getting the response back and page is getting rendered.. Thanks for ur quick response @Kukelje

Comment: Them I'm lost...hope someone else has ideas.

Keep in mind that everything you post that is not in line with reality can be misleading to others and have them spent time chasing ghosts... next time please start with better posts

Comment: @kukelteg thanks for your input next time I shall keep that in mind.. Look at the problem summary... I tried to summarize the problem. Question is how primefaces generating the URL in the page that is the key to this discussion... Thanks for ur help

Comment: No…  pf does it correctly, since I, in several projects, do not have a problem, nor do several thousand others.  Pf does it like other jsf component sets.  It must be something on your side or your setup

Answer (score 0):

Upon further digging thro the rest of the config files. Added the following line to servlet context.

```
<!-- Enable processing of JSF 2 resource requests. For example: /webflow-primefaces-showcase/app/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js?ln=javax.faces   -->

<faces:resources />
```

and now the theme is getting applied without any issues. Thanks for all those who chimed in.